# Django autocomplete with multiplechoice give me invalid form

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light and I'm trying to make form like this:

```
from dal import autocomplete

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    week_number = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=generate_week_numbers(), label=_("Week number"),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
        required=False
    )

    units = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(url='units-ac'), required=False
    )
```

And autocompletes's code:

```
class UnitsAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Unit.objects.none()
    Unit.objects.filter(#somefilters#)

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

    return qs
```

And when I sumbit the form I get an error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>units<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 24 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the examples from the official documentation? 
http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#create-an-autocomplete-view
You miss the queryset attribute in week_number field.